# android raw query

Tags: android, sql, database

im trying to display items in a list view based on my raw query.
Basically when the user click a list item from screen 1, it adds its name as an extra. 
Then in the next screen im trying to see if my other table in the datbase has any fields with that same name.

table 1                table2
name                    name

check to see if name(table 1) matches name(table 2)

cant get it to match at all.

any help would be brilliant

Comment: Can you post the code used to put extra and get the value in next screen. I think format of the data is creating problem here. It is not coming out as proper string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try{
   File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/filename.txt");
   fileIS = new FileInputStream(f);
   BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIS));
   String readString = new String(); 
   //just reading each line and pass it on the debugger
   while((readString = buf.readLine())!= null){
      Log.d("line: ", readString);
   }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is how you can read the file. Just make a copy of this file and save it to your /data/data/PACKAGE/folder

Comment: ok , that brill, is there any way of doing it so u can actually browse through a pick the file instead of hard code. ta

Comment: Sure, you may use this: http://www.openintents.org/en/node/159 . This is, of course, not very comfortable, but it provides you PICK_FILE http://www.openintents.org/en/node/164 
and 
PICK_DIRECTORY http://www.openintents.org/en/node/165 which is very comfortable and user friendly) To my mind =)

Comment: No problemz =) The best reward is a plus to post and visiting my blog sometimes..heh. Good luck!